# Getting the display text of an object

Tags: linden-scripting-language

I would like to know whether there is any mechanism to retrieve the display text of an object. As far as I know, there's no direct LSL function for that.

Isn't there any property that we can use to extract this information?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean the text that hovers over an object:

That text is set by calling [llSetText](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlSetText), but there is no corresponding llGetText. Instead, you can use [llGetPrimitiveParams](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlGetPrimitiveParams) with the constant PRIM_TEXT, like so:

```
list params = llGetPrimitiveParams([PRIM_TEXT]);
string text = llList2String(params, 0);
```

Comment: I tried this and it works well... sura maybe accept this answer?